# How to create photo icons for the buttons in the sliding menu in Android?

Tags: android, button, icons, slidingmenu

I just started developing for Android. How can I add photo icons for the buttons in the sliding menu?

Comment: Which sliding menu are you talking about?

Comment: Please add more detail to your question, it's very hard to understand what problem you're facing.